# How can I replace NA values for a specific condition in RStudio?

Tags: r

I'm taking an Advanced Business Analysis class for school and we're learning to program in R Studio.

The professor shared a hint to help us solve a problem, but I'm unable to get it to work.

I'm trying to set the mean height by gender for any height values that contain NA.

Here's what the professor shared as a solution to the problem, but it doesn't work. Nothing gets updated in the data table:

```
data$height[is.na(data$height) && data$gender == "female"] = data$height[data$gender=="female"]
```

I tried this:

```
data$height[is.na(data$height) && data$gender == "female"] = mean(data$height[data$gender=="female"])
```

and this:

```
data$height[is.na(data$height) && data$gender == "female"] = mean(data$height[data$gender=="female"], na.rm = TRUE)
```

But got this error:

```
In mean.default(data$height[data$gender == "female"]) :  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

I calculated the mean height of each gender and tried it this way, but that didn’t work either. In all scenarios, the height still displays “NA”.

```
femaleMeanHeight = mean(data$height[data$gender=="female"], na.rm = TRUE)
data$height[is.na(data$height) && data$gender == "female"] = femaleMeanHeight
```

I don't know where else to go. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's hard to know exactly how to help without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5325862) that shows exactly what you're trying to do and what's going wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There two problems with your code. The first is in`data$height[is.na(data$height) && data$gender == "female"]` and the second is in `mean(data$height[data$gender=="female"])`.

We start with the **second problem** - you already solved it. Calculating a mean and including NA will result in NA. Therefore you set `rm.na = TRUE`, so the NAs will be ignored. (Replacing NA with NA doesn't make sense or a difference )

The **first problem** is the && part. There is a difference between & and &&. Just use & instead of && and your code might run.

```
data$height[is.na(data$height) & data$gender == "female"] = mean(data$height[data$gender=="female"], na.rm = TRUE)
```

Like I mentioned && and & have different meanings.

& does exaclty what you want. It tests for every row if your two conditions are true or false (Is `height` NA and is `gender` female?). The result will be a vector (for each row one logical) for example `TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE` (The first and third row meet the condtions). The new mean height will just overwrite the height in the rows with `TRUE`. --> That's what you want.

&& will only test the first row. So you just get one `TRUE` or `FALSE`. If your first row has NA in `height` and female in `gender` you get a `TRUE`. And your whole dataset will be overwritten with the mean (data$height[TRUE] - would mean everything in the column height). If your first row is not female or height has a value, the result will be `FALSE`. So no height will be overwriten with the mean height.

So the reason for *nothing worked* might be that your first row didn't match your conditions - therefore the result was `FALSE`. And overwrite data$height[FALSE] with mean implys replace NA with the mean height in no row at all.